# share virtualbox os with multiple ubuntu users

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, administration

i have an ubuntu install with user account of myself and my brother sister father. recently install windowsxp on virtualbox on myside. how can i let my other users (brother sister etc ) to have access to the same virtualbox windowsxp.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it has answered your question. Use the check/tick button next to the answer to accept an answer

Comment: Has it solved your issue? Why don't you consider commenting or accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the virtual machine will be located in Home > VirtualBox VMs. Find the folder corresponding to your virtual machine inside this folder.

Move(better copy and then delete :p) the entire folder into some other place(a common hard disk partition) where all your user accounts have access.

Just double click the `yourVM.vbox` file after moving. That will launch the virtual box with VM added to the list.

You may want to remove the Old entry if it is conflicting.